# Set cookie on Magento with store language

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to set a cookie that contains the current store's language(id).

I found some useful functions:

- to get the store's id/code:

  Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();

  or

  Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
- to set the cookie according to getStore() result:

  setcookie("storeLang", $value , time()+3600,"/");

I need to know where I can add this code (what file), to make this work.

Comment: Without a use case its impossible to tell on which event you should register your hook on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've done this in the past:

Take the code that sets the cookie, put it in a javascript file (stored in js/COMPANY_NAME/your_cookie_file.js normally).

Then add the javascript file to the head of your document with a local.xml action method.

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="addJs"><script>COMPANY_NAME/your_cookie_file.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

Then either call the setcookie() function via an onclick="setcookie(this.value)" or onchange="setcookie(this.value)" in the .phtml file passing the value you want (if you are waiting for the user to change it etc.) or have a window.onload function in your .phtml file something along the lines of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    window.onload = setcookie('storeLang',<?php echo some php code for the value ?>,time()+3600,'/');
//]]>
</script>
```